# DS-160 primary occupation of 14 year old dependent

Tags: visas, usa

I have a 14-year-old minor dependent for whom I am filling DS-160 for H4 nonimmigrant visa. For the first time, there is a section of primary occupation in her DS-160.

The only applicable options I can see are `student` or `not employed` for primary occupation. She is going into ninth grade for the 2023-24 school year this fall. Is the primary occupation of student applicable for her? Or would not employed be better?

Comment: "Student" should be fine here.

Comment: Why do you not want to choose "student" given that she is a student? I don't think the form has any trick questions. For a teenager to be a student is normal and ordinary.

Comment: I guess the confusion may come from calling a schoolkid student. In some versions of English those are different age groups, in other versions the word student covers both age groups.

Comment: @Willeke I agree. In the UK the word “student” would primarily conjure an image of an over-18 university student as opposed to a primary or secondary school *pupil*.

Comment: @Darren "student" is increasingly being used at younger ages in the UK.  It's long been fairly common for sixth formers (16-18) especially at sixth form colleges, but recently I've seen it for the whole of secondary school (11-18) and even (rarely) in a primary (5-11) context.  (ages in brackets for those not familiar with UK school terminology)

Answer (score 14):

There is no need to overthink this question - your daughter is still in school, therefore the correct answer here is **Student**

Comment: In US English the word student covers schoolkids as well as those going to university (and all in between.)

Comment: @Willeke is there English where the word student _doesn't_ include children at school (pre university)?

Comment: I am not sure, I have learned English as a second language but I often see schoolkids pre university not called students, which might be a translation thing or regional differences.

Comment: @Willeke There are other words that can be used for pre-university students, but the word student doesn't exclude them.  You'd often qualify it if needed - school student, high-school student, university student, etc.  but on its own student would cover them all.  Perhaps some locales it doesn't, but I'm not aware of any (I am native NZ English speaker)

Comment: @Midavalo The OED splits university and primary/secondary usage into different sub-entries, attesting the latter to 1764, with a usage note of "rare in British use before the mid 20th cent." (versus c1450 with no note for the former). It's therefore not unthinkable that some South Asian dialects might keep the more restrictive pre-1947 sense, though I don't have direct evidence for that.

Comment: Since the OP tagged this [tag:usa], it's probably safe to presume an American perspective on the word "student". As @Willeke noted, in the US, "Student" covers those from kindergarten through doctoral candidate. Of course, many (most? all?) doctoral candidates are usually employed in some fashion, but they'd still be considered a "student".